# PyTorch How to code Multi Head Self Attention in parallel?

Tags: nlp, pytorch

I want to encode the word (embedding) sequence with 16-Head Self-Attention.

Currently I use a `nn.ModuleList` together with a `for` loop to generate the output of each head then concatenate all of them. This approach is extremely slow and I wonder if there's way to code MHA in parallel?

To generalize, I would like to know if I can 'stack' multiple `nn.Linear`, as I feed the input vector, the multiple outputs will be computed **in parallel**.

Comment: BTW, I don't want to use the nn.MultiheadAttention library because I would like to customize the formation of value vector of each head.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Since `nn.Linear` is acctually an affine transformation with a weights matrix and a bias matrix, one can easily wrap such matrices in `nn.Parameter` and take advantage of `broadcast semantics` to achieve the goal.

---

Edit: I also find a `nn.Linear(d_model, n_heads*d_key)` functions identically.